# How to put JavaScript in Laravel make:auth

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, vue.js

Hello everyone so new to laravel here, I just want to ask how to put JS into the file that automatically created when running `php artisan ui vue --auth`, because whenever I try to add it into `resources/views/auth/register.blade.php` I get

> [Vue warn]: Error compiling template:
>   Templates should only be responsible for mapping the state to the UI. Avoid placing tags with side-effects in your templates, such as , as they will not be parsed.

sorry for random question I just want to know how, and also how to add css, thank you so much in advance

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">Dashboard</div>

            <div class="card-body">
                @if (session('status'))
                    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                        {{ session('status') }}
                    </div>
                @endif

                You are logged in!
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

more code here since they dont allow

@endsection

Comment: fix the command sir, sorry for that, since its generated from running ```php artisan ui vue --auth``` and its showing Vue warning whenever I try adding <script></script> into the end of it

Comment: there sir added some code, thank you for noticing me and answering my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to add a `<script>` to your blade `@section`, which is why you're getting that error. There are a few ways to do this.

**1**.. Add your script tags to `views/layouts/app.blade.php` right before the `</body>` tag, for example:

```
<script></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**2**.. Place them in your `<head>` tag and add the defer attribute

`<script defer></script>`

Your `register.blade.php` and any other view that extends `app.blade.php` will now have access to these scripts because it extends the `app.blade.php` layout.

**3**..  Use the Blade `@stack` directive to push your script to a stack. Stacks can be named, in this example lets simply use the name `scripts`. Add this to `register.blade.php`

```
@push('scripts')
<script></script> <!-- Add your JS file or JS code -->
@endpush`
```

Now in the `<head>` tag of your `app.blade.php` you can place `@stack('scripts')`

**Note**: Only `register.blade.php` will load this script, any other view that extends `app.blade.php` will not have access to it.